# Issues accessing variables from .env file

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, .env

I have been trying to get my API key from my .env file that is at the root of my folder of my Vite app to a JSX file where I want to do the fetching, but each time I use `process.env.{MY_VARIABLE_NAME}` the browser console returns an error:

> ReferenceError: process is not defined

The line where I am trying to get data from the API:

```js
const api = await axios.get(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apikey=${process.env.RECIPE_API_KEY}`)
```

I checked around and I have tried installing dotenv and it still not works

Can anyone help with this, and if there is any more information that will be needed, I am available to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that, since I am using a Vite React app, to access the variables in the .env file `import.meta.env.{MY_VARIABLE_NAME}` should be used instead of `process.env`.

And my I have to add a VITE_ prefix to the start of the variable name in both my .env file and where I am trying to access the API key.

Answer (score 1):

The process object is not available in the client side javascript environment, if you were running this on server side runtime it would work.

Comment: I understand that, but I am following a tutorial and I did basically the same thing the tutor did and it is giving an error he did not encounter.

Comment: can you pls share the link where you found this?

Comment: If it is the link to the tutorial, then: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xc4uOzlndAk&t=48s

Comment: have you re-build entire project after adding those process variable? It seems the bundler is not properly injecting it into client side.

Comment: I have run the yarn build command on my CLI and it is still giving the issue

Comment: ok, i see they have referenced this github project. Could you please check if this works ? https://github.com/ikramdeveloper/spoonacular-recipes-app-react

Answer (score 1):

You may try by assigning it to the variable and then use it as:

```
const API= process.env.RECIPE_API_KEY;
const api = await axios.get(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apikey=${API}`)
```

I think this will work

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I just tried this and it is still giving the same error

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a React app or a bundler like Webpack, and you want to use environment variables directly on the client side without any build process, you can expose the environment variables in your server's response and access them in your client-side JavaScript code.

Comment: Can I be having this issue because I used yarn create vite?